# .Net Core IFilter inherited interfaces wont't execute any methods

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, ifilter

I have a class inheriting from `ActionFilterAttribute` and `IActionFilter`. Now I'm implementing the interface methods and applied the filter to the controller and action too. Nothing happens ...

I ensured it by applying some breakpoints all over the filter. To clarify I'm using `System.Web.Mvc.Filters` and that's most of it I just want to have a filter that the action goes to before it gets executed.

```
public class AuthJwtFilter : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    public string Realm { get; set; }

    void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var request = true;
    }
}
```

And just a break point on `var request` to see if it gets in.

```
[AuthJwtFilter]
    [HttpGet("/test")]
    public IActionResult Test()
    {
        return Ok("Hello");
    }
```

And that is the Controller Action

Comment: Yes, we need the code.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `IActionFilter` interface from the class declaration. `ActionFilterAttribute` already implements that interface.

Override the base method:

```
public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    var request = true;
}
```

That should work.

**UPDATE**: By the way, if you want your filter to fire *before* the action executes, you should be overriding `OnActionExecuting` instead.

Comment: BTW, I tried adding some other out-of-the-box filter and it didn't fire. May be I'm wrong about that but [HttpGet] is fine but [Authorize] is dead.

Comment: @SlavKirilov: I see. What version of MVC are you using?

Comment: @SlavKirilov: By the way, the correct namespace should be System.Web.Mvc.

Comment: my `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc` is 5.2.3 . I don't exactly know where to check my `System.Web.Mvc` version But in my "using" section I've declared `System.Web.Mvc.Filters`

Comment: I think I know what is going on. That's not the right namespace. You must have  `System.Web.Http.Filters` in the using statements. Remove  `System.Web.Http.Filters` and add `System.Web.Mvc`.

Comment: I guess it's something with the fact the I'm using Asp.Net Core and thus nothing ever works :D